# Java: How can I instantiate a parent object from child without using parent constructor?

Tags: java, oop, object, inheritance, reflection

Here's the example:

```
public class Car{
  private float param;
  public Car(float rawParam) {
    // process rawParam before assign it to this.param
    this.param = rawParam * 2;
  }
}

public class Truck extends Car{
  public Truck(Car car) {
    // How do I instantiate Car?
  }
}
```

There's no default constructor, so I can't just create some arbitrary parent object then clone the passed car by reflection.
The only constructor provided needs some raw params which are unknown to the parent object itself.
How can I instantiate Car and Truck in this case? Thanks!

Comment: You can't. What value `param` would have in that case ? You have to call `super(float)`. To be honest, a `Truck` is not a `Car` ... both are `Vehicule`. Last thing, what is `param` ? What is the context of that value for `Car` and for `Truck`?

Comment: `public Truck(Car car)` <- That looks more like the signature of a typical copy constructor. Aka: You construct a new truck by passing an existing car and the new truck will copy the values of the passed car.

Comment: If you know which `rawParam` value to pass when you construct a `Car`, you should know which `rawParam` value to pass when you construct a `Truck`, so the `Truck` constructor can accept `rawParam` and pass it to the parent constructor.

Comment: I also think `Truck(Car car)` looks like a copy ctor (which Java does not support).  Take a look though at `Cloneable` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html This a bit tricky but it's basically Java's answer to copy ctor.  There are some gotchas though: https://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/cloning/a-guide-to-object-cloning-in-java/ and do some other web searches to learn more.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS That's exactly what I want.

Comment: so you basicly have to pass every values of the `Car` instance. Here `super(car.getParam());`. Careful to NPE in those concept FYI : I still found that strange to copy a `Car` to get a `Truck` ... unless you have a `Transformer` class ... but I don't really see how Optimus would become a Car...

Comment: @AxelH Since (for whatever reason) the constructor of Car multiplies the passed parameter by 2 I'm not sure if it shouldn't be super(car.getParam()/2) to end up with Car and Truck having the same value in `param`. Also of course this assummes that there is a getter for `param` to begin with.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS true and true! I changed that in my "answer", it is too late to edit my comment...

Comment: @Eran Good point. But I'm just curious about the possibility: What if I don't know them in advance? What if I want to add some more fields into an existing class/object :)  (bytecode manipulation seem overkill and slow to me, and no I don't want to convert all my codes to JavaScript)

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS just an illustration =))) How about an non-invertible function :)

Comment: @AxelH I think your answer is the final conclusion: there's no way to do it. PS: God I literally broke into laughter when I read your second comment. Your answering style makes this website so wonderful to learn :) Have a nice day!

Comment: "_there's no way to do it_" @MinhNghĩa no way to do what exactly ? My answer prove you this is possible. I invite you to comment on it if you didn't understand something. (You are welcome for the laugh)

Answer (score 0):

If what you want his instance a `Truck` based on the value of another instance of `Car`, so copy a `Car` into a `Truck`, using your constructor, this COULD look like this :

```
public Truck(Car car) {
    super(car.getParam());
}
```

**Assuming `getParam` exists and return the value you want!!**

Note that if `car`is null, you will received a `RuntimeException` (a `NullPointerException`), and you can't check that since `Super` need to be the first statement.

Well, you can but in some ways, like using a ternary operation :

```
public Truck(Car car) {
    super(car != null ? car.getParam() : -1);
}
```

There are other solution but this is not the point here.

Comment: no in my imaginary world that magical function doesn't exist =))) I asked myself this question when I was working on a library, so I can't touch that Car class. AS @Eran pointed out, if I had designed the classes, I would've know what to feed a Bumblebee to make him Prime

Comment: @MinhNghĩa well you have a bigger problem then, you don't understand JAVA and OO. This is not like in javascript where you can check if a variable exist (unless you start using reflection). You define a specific set of variable, this is a contract. Any other solution would be messy (a Map of Object for example).